# Why does Array.some() not return true?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to find out whether a user has made a request already. The router below uses the Array.some() function to find the userID, but it always returns false.

```
router.post('/requests/myStatus', auth, (req, res) => {
  const userID = req.user
  const listing = req.body.listing
  try {
      Listing.findOne({ _id: listing }).then(listing => {
        if (listing.members.includes(userID)) {
          res.status(200).send({ msg: 'Joined' })
        } else if (listing.requests.some(request => request.user == userID)) {
          res.status(200).send({ msg: 'Requested' })
        } else {
          res.status(200).send({ msg: 'Empty' })
        }
    })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).send(error)
  }
})
```

I find the desired listing and check whether the user with ID X is already a member, if not I check whether he has made a request already.

Trying this code snippet in the [MDN console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) returns true as expected.

```
const array = [ { status: 0, user: '5dd69677de9b1e3484de78af' } ];
console.log(array.some((element) => element.user == '5dd69677de9b1e3484de78af'));
```

The array above depicts the actual response I'd get. I've logged the userID as well as request.user to make sure they are actually the same. I've logged the requests array, the entire listing and everything in between. Replacing userID by a string with the ID in the some-function didn't help either. My co-worker and I are at a loss...

The relevant part of the mongoose schema:

```
const listingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  members: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Profile'
   }],
  requests: [{
    _id: false,
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Profile'
     },
    status: {
      type: Number, // 0 - pending | 1 - accepted | 2 - declined | 3 - withdrawn | 4 - expired
      default: 0
    }
   }]
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: As requested, the listing.requests output:

```
[ { status: 0, user: 5dd69677de9b1e3484de78af } ]
```

EDIT 2: Casting the compared IDs to a string solved the issue. Thanks @Grynets

Comment: show me your ( listing.requests ) data

Comment: @PrakashKarena I've updated the post. As I said the array in the code snippet is pretty much the exact output I'd get in the real app

Comment: @NinaScholz In that case listing.members should be empty as well, but that works as intended

Comment: Checking whether the requesting user has an authentication token. If so the user's ID is forwarded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your snippet

```
[ { status: 0, user: 5dd69677de9b1e3484de78af } ]
```

I guess that `req.user` is string, but you're trying to compare string to mongo _id value, which is not of type string.

Maybe, try to cast both values to string?

```
listing.requests.some(request => request.user.toString() == userID.toString())
```

Of course, only if `userID` is really present

Comment: That actually did the trick. I was sure that == would convert types as nevessary.

Comment: @Zitrooone `===`does it.

Comment: @reporter According to MDN == converts to common type, while === compares type and value
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness
Hence why I'm still very puzzled as to why it didn't work initially, but whatever

Comment: @Zitrooone you're correct that `==` does conversion while `===` doesn't. However, it's not clear what data you have - `5dd69677de9b1e3484de78af` is not a valid number, as JS doesn't format numeric values as hex. My guess is that it's a custom type (so, an object) which is merely *printed* to look like a number. Since you handle the print value through the `toString()`, then calling `request.user.toString()` would produce the primitive value `"5dd69677de9b1e3484de78af"`. If `userID` is of the same type, then `toString()` on it would produce an equivalent primitive string which are then compared

Comment: @VLAZ It's an ObjectID, so indeed a custom type. Yet I thought the loose comparison would convert both to a string (userID coming from a json body should already be a string I suppose). Going forward I will just default to casting IDs to a string before comparing to save myself another headache...